# bash string extraction

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to extract the 2nd field from the last part of the following strings:

```
foo_1.103.debug_xx.ver21-inc-1          --> string extracted "debug_xx"
foo_1.103.1.0.release_32_xx.ver21-inc-1 --> string extracted "release_32_xx"
foo_1.103.1.0.release_xx.ver21-inc-1    --> string extracted "release_xx"
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `${VAR%PATTERN}` to remove the suffix corresponding to the last field, then `${NEWVAR##PATTERN}` to remove the prefix corresponding to all but the last remaining field.

```
all_but_last_field=${mystring%.*}
second_to_last_field=${all_but_last_field##*.}
```

You need to store the string in a variable and store the intermediate result in a variable as well, you can't directly chain the expansions (you can in zsh, but not in bash).

Comment: you have a minor typo, your second statement should have referred to **$all_but_last_field** like `second_to_last_field=${all_but_last_field##*.}`. I'm accepting your answer as it's pure bash but the answer of Drake Clarris was great as well. It's actually even more compact but I can only choose 1 answer. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 5):

With pure `bash`:

```
IFS='.' read -a p <<< 'foo_1.103.1.0.release_32_xx.ver21-inc-1'
echo "${p[${#p[@]}-2]}"
```

You can do it easier with `awk`:

```
awk -F. '{print$(NF-1)}' <<< 'foo_1.103.1.0.release_32_xx.ver21-inc-1'
```

In case your strings to parse are file names, you can still do it with `awk`:

```
awk -F. 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++){$0=ARGV[i];print$(NF-1)}}' foo*
```

Comment: `+1` for the best possible answer. Your `echo` would be nicer thus: `echo "${p[@]:(-2):1}"`.

Comment: Cleaner, shorter, faster. Great one, @gniourf_gniourf.

Comment: gniourf_gniourf & manatwork: great solution. I'm not so well versed with awk but with your help, I'm learning some more about it. +1 to both of you :)

Answer (score 2):

A `sed` command to do it:

```
sed 's/foo_[0-9.]*\([^.]*\).*/\1/' inputfile
```

Assuming, of course, that `inputfile` contains your strings, each on its own line (as your example appears to be). If say you are using file names, then piping the results of `ls` into the `sed` will work as well.

Comment: Good one, but that `[0-9.]` is its weakness – will fail on a file name like “foo_1.103b.debug_xx.ver21-inc-1”. Better rely strictly on dots: `sed 's/.*\.\([^.]*\)\.[^.]*$/\1/'`.

Comment: Yeah I used the numbers because in his example that seemed more consistent than the dots.

Comment: +1 to Drake Clarris for providing original solution and +1 for you manatwork too for reviewing the code. But yup, I agree with the Drake Clarris' solution, he was trying to be much more practical. But your solution would help in case my pattern changes :)

Answer (score -2):

assuming those are files:

> ls foo*|awk -F. '{print $3}'

Comment: -1 It is not the third column based on dots for all entries

Comment: oh really? As far as I know the index start at 1 not 0 ... 
And just tested it under linux bash 4.1.2 ...
foo_1.103.debug_xx.ver21-inc-1
$1= foo_1
$2=103
$3=debug_xx
$4=ver21-inc-1
test it for yourself ...

Comment: Test it again: http://pastebin.com/wvsPm7AV

Comment: http://pastebin.com/M0rnVMUT

Comment: Be sure to have the exact same input. There are terms foo_1.103 and foo_1.103.0.1

Comment: k, need to pay more attention to the input !!:/ thanks I missed that.

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`. -1

Comment: saying don't it's easy ... care to explain? why not parse the output of ls taking into account that I'm limiting to the files that I know, besides if you want to do it based on filenames what would you to??? send to a file and then parse the file?

Comment: @AlexandreAlves, gniourf_gniourf is referring to GreyCat's [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) article. In case the file names would contain space, like “foo_1.103.de bug_xx.ver21-inc-1”, your `ls` based solution would display “de\ bug_xx”. This can be corrected with `ls`'s `--quoting-style=literal`. But if the file names would contain new line, the parsing would became more complicated.

Comment: @AlexandreAlves, if you will notice, the one I'm interested at is not always at the 3rd column but is always 2nd from last column. So  your solution from the very beginning was faulty. But thanks for trying :)